# Chrome port forwarding not working for https port

Tags: google-chrome, https, google-chrome-devtools, portforwarding

I went through [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server) to setup port forwarding in chrome.

Though I was able to work it out for non-secure (http) ports, I couldn't get it working for secure (https) ports. In both cases (http and https) the page loads in my laptop. just the https page doesn't load in my android phone.

Here is the configuration for http site.
[image: http port forwarding config]

[image]

[image]

And here is the configuration for https site.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

It took me almost a week to find this workaround. **You don't need to root your device, or use a proxy** with this method.

You just need to `port forward on chrome` as you did and `edit an android hosts file` using Virtual Hosts. The `apk` is available under [Virutal hosts releases](https://github.com/x-falcon/Virtual-Hosts/releases) in case [the direct link](https://github.com/x-falcon/Virtual-Hosts/releases/download/2.1.0/app-Github-release.apk) does not work.

On your device, create a `hosts.txt` to map IP addresses to host names:

```
127.0.0.1 domain.com
127.0.0.1 subdomain.domain.com
```

Select your hosts file and turn it on! Then install certificates on your device.
[image: Virtual hosts app]